# How does a trap affect external programs?

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix, subshell, trap

> When a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored shall be set to the default actions

Source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_28

Apparently, this is also true for external programs that I'm calling from my shell. `trap "" SIGNAL` works to trap (ignore) that signal. But `trap action SIGNAL` doesn't call `action`, doesn't do anything, and the signal handling seems to be set to its original default.

Where is this behavior defined?

Comment: Maybe I'm just overlooking it in that Open Group document. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trap` is a builtin of the shell that gives an interface to `signal()` / `sigaction()`. The behaviour wrt external command in that regard is the same as in other languages where you change signal disposition.

When you execute another command by way of the `execve()` system call, the memory of the process including the code, so including the code of signal handler is wiped to be replaced by that of the new executable, so there's no way signal handlers could survive.

[POSIX says about `execve()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> Signals set to the default action (`SIG_DFL`) in the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image. Except for `SIGCHLD`, signals set to be ignored (`SIG_IGN`) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image. **Signals set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image** (see `<signal.h>`).
>
> If the `SIGCHLD` signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, it is unspecified whether the `SIGCHLD` signal is set to be ignored or to the default action in the new process image.

`trap '' NAL` sets the `SIG_IGN` disposition for the signal and `trap - NAL` `SIG_DFL`.

`trap` has additional requirements (many of which could be seen as limitations and that some shell implementations ignore):

- while a process inherits signal handlers upon forking, in shells handlers are reset in subshells. For some signals, that's useful like the SIGINT/SIGQUIT/SIGHUP/SIGTSTP that are often sent to both parent and child, sometimes not.
- POSIX shells are forbidden to allow users to restore handlers for signals that were ignored upon start.
- some signals are automatically ignored in asynchronous commands.
- mingling with SIGCHLD is often not working as the shell does its own handling  of it.
- <sub>I've always found signal handling in shell scripts to be unreliable and unportable in general.</sub>